# Click Button as long as Button is available python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently doing a small Python Script for my Boss, and in general i just need to click a Button on a Website to load more Objects. There are like 50 Objects automatically showed, but u can click on "more" till there are like 5000 objects.

How can i check if the Button is still on the page or rather clickable for my While loop.

```
button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "mod-LoadMore--button")

while *button is available*:
    button.click()
```

I tried it with:

```
while button != None:
```

and stuff, but not figured out how to exactly do it...
Hope u can help me with this